# Javascript Resize to reset variables

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope, reset

I'm trying to have a bunch of variables reset themselves on a resize (I'm just a little crazy like that. Yes, I know virtually no one will do it as their using the page). I want to be able to have the plugin that I created (hScroll) reset it's variables when the user resizes the page. I only want to declare them and set them within one line, so I tried using the window.variableName = ... but that didn't seem to work. Once again, all I want to be able to do is have to declare and set the variable within one line, and on resize, have the variables reestablish themselves, since a few are size dependent. As you can see, I have also tried the triggerHandler method as well, but it does not seem to be working.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    hScroll: function(options) {
      var defaults = {
        container: "nav",
        sliderName: ".sliderName",
        partContainer: ".beep"
      };
      var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
      return this.each(function() {

        // I want to set global variables and have them reset... START
        var slider = $(o.container + " " + o.sliderName),
          sliderWidth = slider.outerWidth(),
          container = $(o.container),
          containerWidth = container.outerWidth(),
          containerInnerWidth = containerWidth - (2 * parseInt(container.css("padding-left"))),
          sliderPieces = slider.children(o.partContainer),
          numberOfPieces = sliderPieces.length,
          containerWidth = $(o.container).width(),
          piecesWidth = 0;

        // set slide widths
        if (containerInnerWidth > sliderWidth / numberOfPieces) {
          piecesWidth = sliderWidth / numberOfPieces
        } else {
          piecesWidth = containerInnerWidth;
        }
        sliderPieces.width(piecesWidth);

        // set gutter and how many pieces can be seen at once.
        var wholePiecesSeen = Math.floor(containerInnerWidth / piecesWidth),
          gutter = parseInt((containerInnerWidth - (wholePiecesSeen * piecesWidth)) / 2);


        // END - I want this block to be reset when the window is resized.


        var isContainerBigEnough = function() {
          if (containerInnerWidth > sliderWidth) {
            $(o.container).removeClass("tooBig");
          } else {
            $(o.container).addClass("tooBig");
          }
        }
        isContainerBigEnough();

        // arrow variables

        $(o.container + " .previous").click(function() {

          var addOn = 0,
            newPosition = 0,
            thisFarGone = parseInt(slider.css("left")),
            moveThisFar = piecesWidth,
            allTheWay = containerInnerWidth - sliderWidth;

          // always make sure to center your tiles
          if (thisFarGone == allTheWay) {
            moveThisFar = moveThisFar - gutter;
            console.log(moveThisFar);
            console.log("in");
          };

          newPosition = -thisFarGone - moveThisFar;

          //make sure it doesn't go too far
          if (newPosition < 0) {
            newPosition = 0;
          }
          newPosition = parseInt(newPosition); // - addOn);
          slider.css({
            "left": (-newPosition) + "px"
          });
        });
        $(o.container + " .next").click(function() {
          var addOn = 0,
            newPosition = 0,
            thisFarGone = parseInt(slider.css("left")),
            moveThisFar = piecesWidth;

          // always make sure to center your tiles
          if (thisFarGone == 0 ||
            thisFarGone == -0 ||
            thisFarGone == undefined) {
            moveThisFar = moveThisFar - gutter;
          };

          newPosition = moveThisFar - thisFarGone;
          //make sure it doesn't go too far
          if (newPosition > sliderWidth - containerInnerWidth) {
            newPosition = sliderWidth - containerInnerWidth;
          }
          newPosition = parseInt(newPosition); // - addOn);
          slider.css({
            "left": (-newPosition) + "px"
          });
        });

        $(window).resize(function() {
          console.log("working");
          $(o.container).triggerHandler("hScroll");
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".posts-timeline").hScroll({
    container: ".posts-timeline",
    sliderName: "#slider",
    partContainer: ".post"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
        console.log("working");
        $(o.container).hScroll("hScroll");
```

Maybe not exactly that, but if you want those variables to be reassigned, I'm guessing that would wind up being done somewhere in `$(window).resize(function() {`